# Стандартные методы (функции) для работы с массивами в C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Этот вопрос уже наверняка поднимался не раз, но что-то я не могу найти конкретного ответа да или нет. Учу C++, возник вопрос: существуют ли стандартные методы (функции) из встроенных библиотек для работы с массивами (сортировка, БП и т.д.)?

Comment: конкретный ответ - да

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стандартные алгоритмы можно посмотреть [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). Некоторые еще в `numeric` есть. Более продвинутый - [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), но он не встроенный (но планируется к внесению в стандартную библиотеку) и у него плохая документация. Еще есть `boost.range` - там документация получше, но он опять же не встроенный и возможностей поменьше.

Answer (score 4):

Стандартные алгоритмы из `<algorithm>` в большинстве своем работают с итераторами, а указатели считаются итераторами.

Поэтому все эти функции работают и с массивами тоже. Пример:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[5] {5,4,1,2,3};

    std::sort(arr, arr+5);

    for (int x : arr)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```